# MASM giving incorrect results upon entering negative decimals

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, masm32

So, I am writing a program that divides two negative integers and stores the quotient and remainder, but it displays incorrect results.
Here is my code:

```
    mov eax, input1
    mov edx, 0             ; dividend high half = 0.  prefer  xor edx,edx
    mov ebx, input2         ; divisor can be any register or memory
    div ebx
    mov remainder, edx       
    mov edx, offset prompt
    call Writestring
    mov quotient, eax 
    call WriteDec
    mov edx, offset prompt1
    call Writestring
    mov edx, remainder
    call WriteDec
    call Crlf
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`div` is used for unsigned division.  For signed division you want [`idiv`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/idiv).  This takes a signed 64-bit dividend in `edx:eax`, so you don't want `edx` to be zero if the dividend is negative; rather, you want to [sign extend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_extension) `eax` into `edx`.  This can be done with [`cdq`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cwd:cdq:cqo).

So I think you want

```
    mov eax, input1
    cdq 
    mov ebx, input2
    idiv ebx
    mov remainder, edx  
    mov quotient, eax
    ...
```

A couple other remarks:

- Where does `WriteDec` expect to find the number to be written?   Check its documentation. You don't seem to be putting the results in any consistent register.
- You are waiting until after calling `Writestring` to save the quotient from `eax` into memory.  Are you sure `Writestring` won't overwrite `eax`?  Many calling conventions would allow it to.
- Your program will crash with a divide error if `input2` is 0, or if `input1` is `0x80000000` (the most negative 32-bit integer) and `input2` is `-1`.  You may want to do some input checking if you don't already have it elsewhere.
- As your comment says, `idiv` can take its operand from register or memory.  So there is no need to `mov ebx, input2` when you can simply do `idiv input2`.  (Though you may also want to design your program so that `input2` lives in a register all along and never needs to be stored in memory in the first place.)

Comment: Most Irvine32 functions that take an integer take it in EAX (and use a custom calling convention that preserves all registers), so this may actually be correct.  (WriteString really does take its arg in EDX so the quotient really can stay in EAX. http://csc.csudh.edu/mmccullough/asm/help/source/irvinelib/writestring.htm).  Yay for not teaching students about calling conventions!(?)

Comment: Okay, so then the `mov edx, remainder` probably ought to be `mov eax, remainder`.

Comment: Oh, yes, that's a bug.  And it would certainly have been clearer to just store both div results right after div.  (And I might have included a commented-out reload to point out that it's still there.)  It's also unnecessary to use any static storage, just ECX to stash the remainder would work.